# How to create new DataTable with column structure from other DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-4.5

As in title - the question is:

How to create new DataTable with column structure from other DataTable?

I need empty DataTable to use `.Rows.Add()` method in it.

Code:

```
DataTable dtFirst = new DataTable();
dtFirst.Columns.Add("column1");
dtFirst.Columns.Add("column2");
dtFirst.Columns.Add("column3");

FillDataTableFirst(); // before I create second DataTable - dtFirst is filled

// here I need dtSecond DataTable with same column structure
// i cant just copy first data table, because it contains data

DataTable dtSecond = ???;
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the [`.Clone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for the `DataTable.Clone()` method (available since framework version 1.1).

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx):

> Clone creates a new DataTable with the same structure as the original
>   DataTable, but does not copy any data (the new DataTable will not
>   contain any DataRows). To copy both the structure and data into a new
>   DataTable, use Copy.

In your example:

```
DataTable dtFirst = new DataTable();
dtFirst.Columns.Add("column1");
dtFirst.Columns.Add("column2");
dtFirst.Columns.Add("column3");

FillDataTableFirst(); // before I create second DataTable - dtFirst is filled

DataTable dtSecond = dtFirst.Clone();
```

Answer (score 9):

Just use [`DataTable.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) which clones the schema but not the data:

```
DataTable dtSecond = dtFirst.Clone(); // empty
```

Now you can start adding new rows:

```
DataRow newRow = dtSecond.Rows.Add();
newRow.SetField("column1", "Value1");
newRow.SetField("column2", "Value2");
newRow.SetField("column3", "Value3");
```

Comment: `dtFirst.First();` typo? :)

Answer (score 5):

use the [Clone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) method of the DataTable class.